# Hibernate não atualiza informações

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate, jpa

Meu problema se trata de um update sem sucesso segue o código abaixo.

```
EntityManager manager=JpaUtil.getEntityManager();
        EntityTransaction trx= manager.getTransaction();
        trx.begin();
        TypedQuery<Tipi> query = manager.createQuery("from Tipi",Tipi.class);
        List<Tipi> registros= query.getResultList();


        for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
            registros.get(i).setCod(i+1);
            if(i % 20 ==0){
                manager.flush();
                manager.clear();
            }
        }

        trx.commit();
        manager.close();
        JpaUtil.closeFactory();
```

Então como podem ver estou tentando atualizar o campo `cod` inserindo esses 
valores com o loop porém quando executo o código acima o resultado é que só o primeiro registro é atualizado os outros continuam vazios, se eu tirar o `if` ele solta a seguinte `exception`:

> ```
>  Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchedTooManyRowsAffectedException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [4]; actual row count: 3; expected: 1
>     at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1763)
>     at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1677)
>     at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:82)
>     ... 1 more
> Caused by: org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchedTooManyRowsAffectedException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [4]; actual row count: 3; expected: 1
>     at org.hibernate.jdbc.Expectations$BasicExpectation.checkBatched(Expectations.java:89)
>     at org.hibernate.jdbc.Expectations$BasicExpectation.verifyOutcome(Expectations.java:73)
>     at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.BatchingBatch.checkRowCounts(BatchingBatch.java:151)
>     at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.BatchingBatch.performExecution(BatchingBatch.java:128)
>     at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.BatchingBatch.addToBatch(BatchingBatch.java:97)
>     at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3281)
>     at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.updateOrInsert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3183)
>     at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3525)
>     at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityUpdateAction.execute(EntityUpdateAction.java:158)
>     at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:453)
>     at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:345)
>     at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:350)
>     at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:56)
>     at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1218)
>     at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:421)
>     at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.beforeTransactionCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:101)
>     at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:177)
>     at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:77)
>     ... 1 more
> ```

No meu `persistence.xml` o batch size é 20, desde já agradeço qualquer ajuda.

Answer (score 0):

Em contrapartida ao loop, se for conveniente, acho que você deve fazer algo como abaixo (sem percorrer em loop pra retornar lista de objetos):

```
public void saveOrUpdate(T obj) {
    EntityManager manager = ConnectionFactory.getEntityManager();
    try {
        manager.getTransaction().begin();
        if (obj.getId() == null) {
            manager.persist(obj);
        } else {
            manager.merge(obj);
        }
        manager.getTransaction().commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        manager.getTransaction().rollback();
    }
}
```